# Inserting array to BST in-order traverse

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I want to traverse over a given tree using in-order traversal. inserting the sorted array into the BST (keeping it the same shape)

This is my go:

```
public static BinTreeNode<Integer> ARR_TO_BST(BinTreeNode<Integer> root, int[] arr, int ind){

    
    if (root.GetLeft() != null) 
        ARR_TO_BST(root.GetLeft(), arr, ind);

    root.SetInfo(arr[ind]);
    ind+=1;
    
    if (root.GetRight() != null)
        ARR_TO_BST(root.GetRight(), arr, ind);
    
    return root;
```

The problem is that if the array is `arr = {10,20,30,40,50,60}`
and the tree is:

[image]

The return output is a tree that if I do an in-order traversal over it is: 10 20 10 20 10 20 ... and not 10 20 30 40 50 60

I need the output to be the same shape of the picture but with the values of `arr` the algorithm is to traverse -in order on the tree : left subtree - vertex - right subtree
but instead of reading the values we insert the values from `arr` to `root`

I would appreciate help! thank you

Comment: So you have somehow defined tree and an array and you want to create exact same tree but made of items from array so that the inorder traversal is the same as items iteration through the given array?

Comment: @Ecto I defined the tree on my main function, and I want to create a new tree with the same shape but with values of an array (I choose the values)  while keeping the tree BST - which is, in-order traversing it and putting the values from the array: left subtree - vertex - right subtree. In short: yes to your question, in order array of BST = ordered array

Comment: I have post solution, could you check that

Comment: @sc0der Hey thank you for answering, can we accomplish this using only arrays? Or it is not possible?

Comment: @sc0der I need to keep the shape of the tree and the attribute of a BST (left < root <= right) but change the values to be the array's (which is already sorted)

Comment: @StackOMeow , I have updated the solution, could you check that. hope this works!

Answer (score 1):

You never change `ind`. After the first call to `ARR_TO_BST`, it remains what it was before the call. Make `ARR_TO_BST` return the number of elements it placed:

```
    if (root.GetLeft() != null)
        ind = ARR_TO_BST(root.GetLeft(), arr, ind);
    root.SetInfo(arr[ind]);
    if (root.GetLeft() != null)
        ind = ARR_TO_BST(root.GetLeft(), arr, ind + 1);
    return ind;
```

and you should be all right.

Comment: But where do you increment it so that the array values get inserted to the tree? now it does not increment it at all.. no?

Comment: Now it returns: 20 3 10 7 8 9 . I think it is because we only increment on the right subtree...

Answer (score 0):

You can use accomplish by keep tracking the index of each element to add it back to the result array

```
  static class BST {

        private class Node {
            private Integer key;
            private Node left, right;
            private int index;

            public Node(Integer key, int index) {
                this.key = key;
                this.index = index;
            }
        }

        private Node root;
        private int size = 0;

        public void put(int[] arr) {
            if (size >= arr.length)
                return;
            root = put(root, arr[size], size);
            size++;
            put(arr);
        }

        private Node put(Node node, int key, int index) {
            if (node == null)
                return new Node(key, index);
            int cmp = Integer.valueOf(key).compareTo(node.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                node.left = put(node.left, key, index);
            else if (cmp > 0)
                node.right = put(node.right, key, index);
            else
                node.key = key;
            return node;
        }

        public int size() {
            return size;
        }

        public int[] keys() {
            int[] result = new int[size];
            get(root, result, 0);
            return result;
        }

        public void get(Node node, int[] result, int i) {
            if (i >= result.length || node == null)
                return;
            result[node.index] = node.key;
            get(node.left, result, ++i);
            get(node.right, result, ++i);
        }
    }
```

, main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BST bst = new BST();
        bst.put(new int[] { 10, 20, 5, 40, 1, 60, -10, 0 });

        for (int num : bst.keys()) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
    }
```

, output

```
10 20 5 40 1 60
```